# Using a string get a local variable

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have many EditText variables in my class.
cube_11, cube_12, cube_13....cube_99

I have a string which is the name of one of the EditText variable
"cube_11"

Is it possible by using that string name to get the variable.

```
 EditText variable = getVariableByName("cube_11")
 //variable is now the variable cube_11 previously defined.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want an array or collection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define so many variables; you need to define an array of variables.

```
EditText[] cubes = new EditText[100];  // May vary depending on actual number of cubes.
```

Don't forget to fill the array with actual `EditText` objects.

Then you can access them by index:

```
cubes[11]  // or e.g. cubes[0], cubes[12], cubes[99]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do a search by a name related to the EditText, you can just as easily enough Override the EditText component and add a name field to compare against, but still use the array format as suggested by rgettman.